# Eclipse Subversive Compare and Submit

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive

I'm using subversive plugin for Eclipse and I'm having some difficulties.

I have a file opened that someone else already had and committed. We opened the file at the same time therefore when I try to commit mine it is out of date.

I compare the files and revise the changes to make sure nothing is out of place. Once that is done I'd like to commit this "merged" file. However it is still out of date. I know I can update the file but this will merge everything automatically which I don't want.

What is the best way to compare and commit a file?

Thanks in advance for any help

//update

I found something that could possible solve this.

When I get the error that the file is out of date I update it. This will merge automatically but I select edit conflicts. This will bring up the compare screen and then I compare and make my changes. I save the file and mark it as resolved. Now I can commit the file.

The problem with this is it only works if there are conflicts. Otherwise it will automatically merge without consulting me first of the changes made.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in a team then first you have to lock a particular class that you are doing. Now in you case before updating first you

- Right click on a class that is conflicting
- then click on team then click on synchronize with repository
- after than you can see the changes made by you.
- copy the changes made by you on a separate place like notepad.
- then go to team and  revert the changes by you and take update.
- then paste whatever you have done.
- then click commit.

**note:** be sure to take backup of the class to make sure not to lose changes made by you.

Comment: I thought the plugin would be powerful enough to do this. Pretty much to warn me of the changes made before automatically making them. I've updated my question with a half solution.